# Date and time and string in python

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, button, printing

How do I show or output string in Python depending on what day it is, say I want a quote for today shown today and another quote tomorrow.
Something like if date == today’s date print(“quote”) and so on?
It’s for my app, like you access the app, click the button and it shows you today’s quote, and tomorrow the same but a different quote?

Comment: You probably want to get familiar with `datetime` module.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To be able to help you we need to see what you have tried so far. Could you post the code? Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to print the current date you could use the following

```
from datetime import date 

today = date.today()
print(today)
```

all this does is store the date of today in "today"
For the day of posting printing today gives you 2020-02-07

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it helped me I was confused of heavy thinking, but can i somehow combine it with a random module?

Comment: Your question as to combining it with a random module is a bit unclear. Could you perhaps elaborate on what it is you want to do and perhaps show an example of what it is you want to accomplish ?

Comment: Also, if my answer helped would you mind accepting my answer as solution?

Comment: from datetime import date 

today = date.today()
print(today)  

With this written combine it with a list which consists of a bunch of strings like list = [“quote”, “quote”, “quote”, etc] and every day a different string to be shown in output like I enter this program and show me one string today and then enter the program tomorrow again and shows me another different string from that list

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to do ? I unfortunately do not know what it is you want to do from the previous comment. If you wish to return a random string after each value you could use import random and import string to define a randomstring of any choosen length and print this together with today